# How can I find minimum values from array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, minimum

[image]

I want to extract the two points (i.e their values) which are marked with black outline in figure. These minima points are 2 and 5. Then after extraction these marked points coordinates I want to calculate the distance between them.

The code that I am using to plot average values of image, calculate minimas and locations is

```
I1=imread('open.jpg');
I2=rgb2gray(I1);
figure, title('open');
plot(1:size(I2,1), mean(I2,2));
hold on
horizontalAverages = mean(I2 , 2);
plot(1:size(I2,1) , horizontalAverages)
[Minimas locs] = findpeaks(-horizontalAverages) 
plot(locs , -1*Minimas , 'r*')
```

Minima

```
-86.5647
-80.3647
-81.3588
-106.9882
-77.0765
-77.8235
-92.2353
-106.2235
-115.3118
-98.3706

locs =

    30
    34
    36
    50
    93
    97
   110
   121
   127
   136
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question until I looked at your figure. I'll edit and attach the image.

Comment: Can you also post the data you used?

Comment: Assuming you have the Signal Processing toolbox, have you tried [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) (just flip the sign of your input data to find maxima)?

Comment: I think that you are approaching this problem from the wrong angle. If all you're interested in is extracting the two minimum points, then I would recommend to apply a large mean / median filter to remove the local minima. After this, `findpeaks`, or a simple peak detection algorithm like I posted, should work very well. You may want to combine this with a threshold, i.e. only accept minima below `y = 90`. You can tune this based on the data that you have available.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear from your question what you are actually looking for, but the following one liner will get you the local minima:

```
% Some dummy data
x = 1:11;
y = [3 2 1 0.5 1 2 1 0 1 2 3];

min_idx = ([0 sign(diff(y))] == -1) & ([sign(diff(y)) 0] == 1);

figure
plot(x, y);
hold on;
scatter(x(min_idx), y(min_idx))
hold off;
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you use dummy data instead of the data in the question?

Comment: @IKavanagh because the OP did not post data, just the locations and values of minima, not the actual data he used to create the plot

Comment: Basically I am working on eyes tracking part i.e. open and closed eye. above image is about the mean values of open eyes which shows intensity change. so I am interested in those points where intensity changes like from negative to positive image (first change ) and positive to negative (2nd intensity change) so i want these values actually from the whole values of minimas in order to calculate the distance. and these values are minimum values than the other. so i want to extract those two minimum values from the an array

Comment: @usman, perhaps it would help if you annotated your graph with what you mean by that. I don't really understand from your description. Also, not sure if it's relevant, but have you tried applying a simple smoothing filter before finding the minima?

Comment: @Adriaan The posted locations and minima values are the data the OP is working on. Based on his question and the comment here he wants to extract the minimum values (not sure which yet) from the array of minima and calculate the distance between their locations. No extra data is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'findpeaks' function, if you have the signal processing toolbox.

```
[y,locs]=findpeaks(-x)
```

will find the local minima. This function has a ton of options to handle all kinds of special cases, so is very useful.

Comment: Yes felix I have already calculate the minimas with above command, now what i want is to calculate the between desired points. desired points are shown in attached. please have a sight

Comment: diff(locs) will give the distances between the minima. Not sure what you mean by "between desired" ?

Comment: By desired points means, I have 10 Minimas points on my graph, but I am interested in the start and end points means start point is first minima where negative to positive peak occurs and end point is 2nd minima where positive to negative change occurs. eg: my minima points are   -86.5647
  -80.3647
  -81.3588
 -106.9882
  -77.0765
  -77.8235
  -92.2353
 -106.2235
 -115.3118
  -98.3706 and I am interested in 2nd minima 80.36 and 5th minima 77.07. so these are my desired points. what I want is to extract their locs and calculate the distance between them. Have you clear the idea?