# How to extract desired points from graph and calculate distance between them in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am working Eye detection and tracking part. I am using the method to detect open and close eyes by utilizing the intensity changes. First intensity change is from negative to positive peak and 2nd intensity change from positive to negative peak. I have plotted the horizontal average values of an open eye and calculate the minimas. Now i want to extract the desired points as start and end points. these points are marked in graph by black outlines. in graph I am interested in 2nd and 5th minima i want to extract their locs and calculate distance between them.

```
I1=imread('open.jpg');
I2=rgb2gray(I1);
figure, title('open');
plot(1:size(I2,1), mean(I2,2));
hold on
horizontalAverages = mean(I2 , 2);
plot(1:size(I2,1) , horizontalAverages)
[Minimas locs] = findpeaks(-horizontalAverages) 
plot(locs , -1*Minimas , 'r*')
```

Minimas are:

```
  -86.5647
  -80.3647
  -81.3588
 -106.9882
  -77.0765
  -77.8235
  -92.2353
 -106.2235
 -115.3118
  -98.3706
```

Their locs are:

```
    30
    34
    36
    50
    93
    97
   110
   121
   127
   136
```

[image: Minimas plotted graph]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find minimum values from array in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654943/how-can-i-find-minimum-values-from-array-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate through the line data (consisting of data and time) and store the minimum points in descending (or ascending) order in a `n x 2` matrix.

Then, simply select the first (or last) two rows of the matrix and calculate and find the difference in their respective data (I'm assuming that's what you mean by finding the distance between them.)

Comment: jim, I am only interested in the points as shown in figure where negative to positive slope change occurs and then positive to negative change. its like start and end point. have u got it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you have the data or just an image of the graph.  If the latter:  Finding peaks & valleys by eye is not recommended.  I strongly suggest you get a copy of DataThief or Engauge Digitizer and extract the actual x-y data from your image.  You can follow that by either identifying the actual extrema or performing smoothing operations as desired.

If you have the underlying data, then use `findpeaks` or similar tools to identify the extrema.  Once you have the `x,y` points of interest, calculating Cartesian distances is trivial.

Comment: yes exactly i want to extract point of interest to find distance. I already calculated the local minima using findpeaks(-x). Now i want to extract the 2nd and 5th local minima points which are my point of interest automatically to calculate distance.